# Case sensitive search using CONTAINS keyword in SQL Server

Tags: contains

I want to search word from my database, it must be case sensitive. I added full text index feature to my SQL Server and implemented to my table. And I want to use `CONTAINS` keyword for searching which is case sensitive. Is it possible?

```
SELECT * 
FROM ResultDatabase
WHERE CONTAINS(Data ,'letS')
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether string comparisons are case sensitive or not (and other behaviours regarding character operations) is defined by the collation of a database. 
See [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-2017) for details.

You will either have to create a new database with a case sensitive collation

```
CREATE DATABASE MyOptionsTest  
COLLATE French_CS_AS;  -- CS denotes a CaseSensitive Collation CI would denote a CaseInsensitive Collation
GO
```

or update your existing database to a case sensitive collation

```
USE master;  
GO  
ALTER DATABASE MyOptionsTest  
COLLATE French_CS_AS;  
GO
```

Source: [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/set-or-change-the-database-collation?view=sql-server-2017)

**EDIT**
If you need, both, case sensitive and insensitive search on the same database you could either

- use a case sensitive collation and for case insensitive searches use `UPPER`. This *may* fail with some special characters, for instance if they don't have an uppercase variant.

`SELECT * FROM someTable where UPPER(somecolumn) = UPPER('searchterm')`

- explicitely specify the collation in the query

`SELECT * FROM someTable where somecolumn COLLATE French_CS_AS = 'SEARCHTERM'`

Comment: thank you so much, but what if I need to insensitive search after  I change it?